# H5py: fast way to save list of list of numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

How can I save and read efficiently a list of list of numpy.ndarray, with h5py? E.g. I want to save/read:

```
Y = np.arange(3**3).reshape(3,3,3)
X = [[Y,Y],[Y,Y,Y],[Y]]
```

I am looking for the most efficient (no double loops etc) solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume Y is the same type, e.g., int32 or string. Generally, the most efficient way to handle this will be to emit Y as a single vector (flattened) who's length is:

```
totalLen = sum(map(len, X))
offsets  = cumsum(map(len, X))
```

You can stick the offsets into the hdf5 file as well and load it into memory at the start. Then getting list i is just:

```
offsets[i]:(offsets[i+1] - 1)
```